# Can I fly to Cyprus from Brussels with a German residence permit?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, belgium, german-residents

I am a non-EU German resident and want to fly to Southern Cyprus for one week. I read on the Cyprus Embassy website that I only need my passport and my German residence permit to enter the country.

Since I live near the Belgian border, and because of the lack of direct flights from German airports, it's much more convenient for me to travel from a Brussels airport to Cyprus.

Would it cause any problems at the airport if I fly from Belgium to Cyprus with my passport and German residence permit?

Answer (score 3):

Your residence permit is valid for entering and exiting the Schengen Area anywhere, so you can use it at Brussels Airport.